# issue with left side menu and sub menu

Tags: html, css, angular6

I have a left side menu that the sub menu doesn't display properly. When I redirect one to another component it is not working. When I move dashboard to trip component, sub menu list isn't shown. When I refreshed and direct clicked on trip component, that showed sub list. But when I go to dashboard and again click on trip component that doesn't work.

I expect properly working when I move one to another component submenu list are shown.

```html
<div class="left side-menu">

  <div class="sidebar-inner slimscrollleft">

    <div class="user-details">
      <div class="text-center"></div>
      <div class="user-info"></div>
      <div id="sidebar-menu">

        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#" routerLink="/dashboard" routerLinkActive="activemenu" class="waves-effect">
              <i class="mdi mdi-home"></i>
              <span> Dashboard</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" routerLink="/user" routerLinkActive="activemenu" class="waves-effect">
              <i class="mdi mdi-account"></i>
              <span> User</span>
            </a>
          </li>

          <li>
            <a href="#" routerLink="/tripmangement" routerLinkActive="activemenu" class="waves-effect">
              <i class="mdi mdi-bus"></i>
              <span> Trip</span>
            </a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#" routerLink="/place" routerLinkActive="activemenu" class="waves-effect">
                  <i class="mdi mdi-bus"></i>
                  <span>Location</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" routerLink="/triproute" routerLinkActive="activemenu" class="waves-effect">
                  <i class="mdi mdi-bus"></i>
                  <span>Routes</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" routerLink="/ticketprice" routerLinkActive="activemenu" class="waves-effect">
                  <i class="mdi mdi-bus"></i>
                  <span>Ticket Price</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="waves-effect">
              <i class="mdi mdi-bus"></i>
              <span>Bookings</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="">
              <li>
                <a href="#" routerLink="/addbooking" routerLinkActive="activemenu" class="waves-effect">
                  <i class="mdi downloads"></i>
                  <span>Add</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" routerLink="/listbooking" routerLinkActive="activemenu" class="waves-effect">
                  <i class="mdi mdi-bus"></i>
                  <span>List</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>

          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="waves-effect">
              <i class="mdi mdi-clipboard-text"></i>
              <span>Reports</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="">
              <li>
                <a href="#" routerLink="/userreport" routerLinkActive="activemenu" class="waves-effect">
                  <i class="mdi downloads"></i>
                  <span>User Report</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" routerLink="/bookingreport" routerLinkActive="activemenu" class="waves-effect">
                  <i class="mdi mdi-bus"></i>
                  <span>Booking Report</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a class="waves-effect">
              <i class="mdi mdi-settings"></i>
              <span>Settings</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="">
              <li>
                <a href="#" routerLink="/page" routerLinkActive="activemenu" class="waves-effect">
                  <i class="mdi mdi-bus"></i>
                  <span>Page setting</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" routerLink="/general" routerLinkActive="activemenu" class="waves-effect">
                  <i class="mdi mdi-bus"></i>
                  <span>General Setting</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" routerLink="/emailformat" routerLinkActive="activemenu" class="waves-effect">
                  <i class="mdi-email"></i>
                  <span>Email format Setting</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you please explain that sub menu list not shown part i mean is it collapsed or its not displaying ?

Comment: well if you want to add a css for specific sub menus on specific route you can try using it on your ul tag which contains your sub menus
    
    [ngClass]=" 'className' : route.url == '/addbooking' ||  route.url == '/listbooking' " 

and you can add more if you have more routes in one sub menu its very easy this way

Comment: it is collapsed but when I move into another component its not working..and i refershed the page its collapsed

Comment: are you using javascript or jquery to make it collapsible and calling that script file into angular.json or index.html file ? if you are adding scripting through a file like i mentioned than all your js/jquery functions only work once after the page load and when you move to a new components your scripting is no more working.

Comment: share your code you are using to make your list collapsible

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. now i load my jquery file in the all components. and its working. thanks again.